# Correct way to add a Foreign Key within Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use the Entity Framework and want to know the correct way to set a FK to a existing record.

Tables: `Department<(1)----(n)>User`

Here are my trys:

```
//here i want to add a new user to a existing department
using (EDModell.myEntities ctx = new EDModell.myEntities())
{
    User uNew = new User();
    uNew.FirstName = "Foo";

    //1. try
    uNew.DepartmentReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("myEntities.Department", "DepartmentID", 4);
    //2. try
    uNew.Department = ctx.Department.Single(x => x.DepartmentID == 4);

    // add more data and save changes
}
```

The 1. try seems to be a bit insecure according to typos. It compiles without showing a error.

The 2nd requires a database select which isn't needed. In SQL a insert of the id is possible - so why not in entity framework?

Why can't I just set

```
uNew.DepartmentID = 4;
```

Comment: just add the entity to the virtual list for that specific entity, EF will auto resolve this for you

Comment: What do u mean by 2nd is correct? In 2nd try you are just trying to retrieve a row from Department table where DepartmentID == 1.

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx EntityFramework solves this for you automatically if you implement the model right.

Comment: Ok and what is now the answer to my question?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to set it using the foreign key ID (2nd way), to avoid any issues regarding adding the foreign key entity to the database again

Comment: But this reuqires one select for each fk

Comment: Why does it require one select? normally you will get the values from a UI, a forign key will be a drop down list or any type of input field where you will select one entity and you will get the ID and set it as a foreign key, so you will always have the ID without an extra select

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your navigation properties are set correctly, your `Department` DbSet, should have a `Users` collection. So setting the FK relationship would look like this:

```
using (EDModell.myEntities ctx = new EDModell.myEntities())
{
    User uNew = new User();
    uNew.FirstName = "Foo";

    //get your department, either by FindById, Find, Where, Single, First ...
    var department = ctx.Departments.Single(x => x.Id == 4);
    department.Users.Add(uNew);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: But this only works with one fk. If you have multiple (e.g. `Deplartment`, `UserGroup`, `Country`) this won't work

Comment: Then update the remaining relationships accordingly. This isn't part of your question however. The principle stays the same.

Comment: I don't understand what you are implying. If your first or second approach works, why did you ask this question?

Comment: The 1st seems to be a bit insecure according to typos, it compiles without showing a error - the 2nd requires a database select which isn't needed. I'm not happy with both

Comment: The second one isn't really expensive. And if you are concerned about performance, you shouldn't have gone for Entity Framework in the first place.